# How i get value of cell in mysql database and let user enter a number and sum or subtract it to the value in database

Tags: mysql, winforms

I have a list of balance's in the database.

The user enters his id to display his data in datagridview and enter the amount of money he want to withdraw in textbox.

How can I get his balance and add to the money he want to withdraw and then update his data with the new balance?

```
String ^ constring="datasource=Localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234 ";
MySqlConnection ^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
float h = float::Parse(textBox1->Text);
float withdraw=0;

conDataBase->Open();

try{
  withdraw = ValueinDatabase - h;
  query = "Update database.clientinfo set balance='" + withdraw + "' where accountnum='" + this->accountnum_txt->Text + "';";           
  mycmdDtaBase = gcnew MySqlCommand(query, conDataBase);
  myReader = mycmdDtaBase->ExecuteReader();

    }
    while (myReader->Read())
    { }
    conDataBase->Close();

 }
```

Comment: that's BAD code, subject to race conditions, which WILL cause you (or the clients) to lose money. `update... set balance=balance-$withdraw` would be safer.

Comment: Alternately/In addition to the suggestion from @MarcB, you can have a "transactions" table to record all possible adjustments, and just insert the `-$withdraw` amount into that. Any time you want the balance, you sum the transactions; or you can put trigger(s) on the transactions table to update the balance on the clientinfo table whenever a transaction is inserted, updated, or deleted.